# Manage NAT using a tool

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, nat

I have a Raspberry Pi on which I had previously installed Raspbian and am now installing another version on again. It is mainly used to be a test maschine for small programs and primarily as a NAT router.

However, last time I busted the OS, I let my Mac Mini take over the job. But its getting old and I have a strange feeling about it - I think its about to hit the bucket.

Since setting up NAT was a burden last time (`eth0` -> `eth1`) I would like to know if there is a tool that I can use on the command prompt that would let me manage a NAT system. Before that, I used `iptables`. But I never understood its syntax and it made no sense to me whatsoever. I also had to re-connect my Wifi (recognized as `eth0`) every time the router dropped the signal (which it does; my dorm only has internet turned on frpm 6am to 1am the next day).

So if anyone would know of a tool or an easier way to set up a NAT, please let me know! :)

Comment: Have you thought about looking into dedicated firewall distros?  Like [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), [Smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.org/), or [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/index.php)?

Comment: @Nick2253 Honestly, I have never seen these before. I'll look into it, maybe that is exactly what I need. I use `pfctl` on OS X in order to do NAT there. So pfSense sounds interesting. Thanks for showing me!